# why is this website stuck in the pre (lazy) loader?

Tags: lazy-evaluation, loader

quick cry for help: this website "broke" somehow and is stuck in the pre-loader
https://thelosertakesitall.com/ – I want to understand why and how to fix it, thank you!

I tried removing the  elements displaying the loader but then it just stays at a blank screen. I understand the code is old and was set up by someone I do not have contact to anymore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

jQuery is not loaded because of:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://thelosertakesitall.com/' was
> loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
> 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js'.
> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

try to change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Load jQuery library -->
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Load jQuery library -->
```

Comment: thank you that did it! so simple with such a huge impact! take care!